# how to use more than one character in format delimited (AWS Athena)?

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a table in athena that the data comes from a file that has the separator (";") and I'm trying to configure this in the table but it doesn't recognize the complete separator. How do I make it recognize the double quotes?

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\"\;\"' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
```

I tried several ways in the code and it doesn't understand the double quotes

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"\;"' 

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\";\"'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '";"'
```

Comment: Have you tried without the double-quotes? Ie. `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'`.

Comment: is that really need the double-quotes. The separator is (";")

Comment: If this is a csv-file where fields have double-quotes, like `"a";"foo bar";"baz"`, the parser can omit the double-quotes during import.